# Command-line: How can I connect to a wireless network without starting DHCP autoconfig process?

Tags: command-line, wifi, dhcp

I would like to **connect to a wireless** example network (lets assume *no encryption*, in order to make explanations easier) via **command-line**.

I use to perform this procedure:

```
$ nmcli con
```

Example output:

```
NAME            UUID                                   TYPE              TIME
Wireless-1      28d6c265-xxxx-4e83-907f-ecb5ab3ac37c   802-11-wireless   Thu 
Wired-Network   30d29da3-xxxx-4ea2-94ff-0edac8954ff7   802-3-ethernet    Sun
```

So, I try with:

```
$ nmcli con up uuid 28d6c265-xxxx-4e83-907f-ecb5ab3ac37c
```

But this method starts **DHCP autoconfig**, and I would like to **manually config** my network (for auditing matters), perform `netdiscover`... etc.

If I shutdown `network-manager` service, both wireless connection routines and DHCP are disabled.

How could I **connect (associate) to a Wireless** network without IP autoconfig routines start?

Further data:

- Command-line methods are preferred. GUI accepted.
- In my example there is no encryption (WPA nor WEP). I don't know if the procedure depends on this feature.
- I use to work with Ubuntu 16.04, Kali (recent as for June 2017), Raspbyan, Ubuntu Mate and Mint. If possible, **generic answer** for most Linux distros are preferred.
- No need for `nmcli` explicitly. Any other tool could be used, but GPL open source preferred when possible.

Comment: You may need to use `nmcli con edit` (if your version of `nmcli` supports it) or `nm-connection-editor` (gui) and set a static IP address (one that is not going to conflict with a dhcp address on the network).

Comment: Does it have to be `nmcli`? If you connect to an unencrypted Wifi network with `iw`, there's no auto-dhcp, and if you connect to an encrypted one with `wpa_cli`, you can configure it in `/etc/network/interfaces` or a wpa-supplicant config file.

Comment: @dirkt : no need for `nmcli` exactly. Any other tool could be used, but GPL open source preferred when possible. I have edited the original question to reflect.

Comment: Before NM existed (and during the first few years of its existence when I called it Network Mangler), I used [`iw` to configure wireless](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw). It's still around and should do what you want.

Comment: Both `iw` and `wpa_cli` are open source. In fact, `nmcli` uses both of them - it's just a layer above.